# Problem with the python object constructor

Tags: python, oop

es.

```
class item:
    def __init__(self, number:int):
        self.number = number
a = item("ciao")
```

When I instantiate the object I would like to make sure that the name parameter is of type string and otherwise an exception is raised.
"name: str" doesn't actually check that the parameter is of the specified type

Comment: Consider using *isinstance()*

Comment: Please [edit] to make the title more descriptive. I'm thinking something like, "How do I make a constructor check the type of its arguments?" Also, it looks like you changed the code but forgot to update the text to match (`number: int` vs `name: str`). For more tips, see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html):

> The Python runtime does not enforce function and variable type
> annotations. They can be used by third party tools such as type
> checkers, IDEs, linters, etc.

If you would like to enforce the type you can use `isinstance()` function to do so.

```
class item:
    def __init__(self, number: int):
        if not isinstance(number, int):
            raise TypeError('Value should be of type int')
        self.number = number
```

Answer (score 0):

Annotations do not add more than information to the developer about the expected information. This is done through an informal contract because, as we know, simple annotations do not contain syntactic meaning but are accessible at runtime, so we can implement a generic decorator that is capable of checking types from the function annotations.

```
def ensure_types(function):
    signature = inspect.signature(function)
    parameters = signature.parameters

    @wraps(function)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        bound = signature.bind(*args, **kwargs)
        for name, value in bound.arguments.items():
            annotation = parameters[name].annotation
            if annotation is inspect._empty:
                continue
            if not isinstance(value, annotation):
                raise TypeError(
                    "{}: {} doesn't actually check that the parameter"
                    "is of the specified type.".format(name, annotation)
                )
        function(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped


class item:
    @ensure_types
    def __init__(self, number: int):
        self.number = number
```

Answer (score -1):

This might be what you want. You can use `isinstance()` to check if it is a string. I am not used to exeptions, so I don't know if that is written right, but the logic is.

```
class item:
    def __init__(self, name):
        if isinstance(name, str):
            self._name = name
        else:
            self._name = None
            raise Exception


a = item('ciai')
```

Comment: Don't use `Exception`, use a specific exception like `TypeError`. As well, setting `self._name = None` is pointless, and it'd be better if you used a guard statement (`if not isinstance(...): raise ...` instead of a branching conditional. See [Ajay's answer](/a/69690723/4518341) for a better implementation.